# HDFS delete command results in: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and "RemoteException in offerService"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I notice that HDFS delete commands will randomly fail.  For example, in a MapReduce job I delete a directory at startup.  Occasionally it fails with the error below, but will succeed on the second try.

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.delete(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:513)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.delete(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:1862)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$11.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:599)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$11.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:595)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Digging into the datanode logs I see this exception:

```
RemoteException in offerService
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.lang.NullPointerException): java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.blockReport(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.blockReport(DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:175)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.blockReport(BPServiceActor.java:493)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.offerService(BPServiceActor.java:716)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:851)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can't find any help on that, and I'm not sure where else to look.  Does anyone know what that issue is?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS   and hadoop version prints out:

```
Hadoop 2.5.0-cdh5.3.1
Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r 4cda8416c73034b59cc8baafbe3666b074472846
Compiled by jenkins on 2015-01-28T00:41Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 6a018149a764de4b8992755df9a2a1b
This command was run using /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.1-1.cdh5.3.1.p0.5/jars/hadoop-common-2.5.0-cdh5.3.1.jar
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but Cloudera suggested upgrading to 5.3.3:

http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/HDFS-delete-command-results-in-ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException/m-p/31817#U31817